# Writing file from zip file in C++

Tags: c++

I need to unzip a file that I download from the internet, in C++. I've searched around for hours and I can't find anything.

For the moment I'm using libzip, and I can successfully read the file, I just have no idea on how to write it as files in a folder:

```
int unzipFile(std::string zipPath) {
    //Open the ZIP archive
    int err = 0;
    zip* z = zip_open(zipPath.c_str(), 0, &err);

    //Search for the file of given name
    const char* name = "AvaloniaLauncher.exe";
    struct zip_stat st;
    zip_stat_init(&st);
    zip_stat(z, name, 0, &st);

    //Alloc memory for its uncompressed contents
    char* contents = new char[st.size];

    //Read the compressed file
    zip_file* f = zip_fopen(z, name, 0);
    zip_fread(f, contents, st.size);
    zip_fclose(f);

    //And close the archive
    zip_close(z);

    //Do something with the contents    
    printf(contents);


    //delete allocated memory
    delete[] contents;

    return err;
}
```

I only found this snippet on a old thread from '12, so I would't wake that up again.

I now have the uncompressed contents of the file, but how would I go about on writing it?
Thanks.

Comment: `zip_fopen` et al seem to come from [libzip](https://libzip.org/documentation/libzip.html), not from [zlib](https://zlib.net/manual.html). It's useful to know which library you're using so that you can read the manual.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm gonne change it now. I've looked at so many different libraries now, so I got a little confused. Yes it is libzip. I'm updating the post now :)

Comment: I always get the various compression libraries mixed up - they all have a `z`, usually a `lib` and some miscellaneous other characters, just permuted differently. Please do read the manual and ask if you have a _specific_ question though - otherwise this feels very close to a "write my code for me" question.

Comment: For example, [`zip_get_num_entries`](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_get_num_entries.html) followed by [`zip_stat_index`](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_stat.html) for each index seems to do everything you need. I've never done it before, and just glanced at that manual. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: So I think I read the zLib documention before, so maybe I'm a little stupid now...
But yes, those two functions is what I need. And now that I read my question, I can see what you mean with the 'write my code' thing. I will explain better in the post now.

Comment: No worries. Give it a try and tell us where it breaks! I'm not sure what the relative paths look like in practice, for example, and actually creating all the output directories and files requires some coding. Have you tried just opening an [`ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) in binary mode and calling `write`?